# SDcard with android emulator

Tags: android

I have a question i have created sdcard image file using mksdcard 100M sdcard.img and tried alot of tutorials on net to start the emulator with the sdcard . However none is working, I have tried to start the project and add in run configration additional emulator command line options but the sdcard not appearing in the DDMS !! I have tired the command line in cmd emulator -avd  -sdcard  and the emulator starts without the sdcard . So anyone knows what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I am using eclipse and windows7

Comment: Why not use the 'Android SDK and AVD manager' and create an AVD with an SDcard that way, it would be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you should use AndroidSDK and AVD manager. Then create an AVD with an SDcard and then push file into SDcard through DDMS perspective. I don't know how to push more than 1 file at a time though. Any sugesstion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AndroidSDK and AVD manager  in EClipse. Using this you can create new AVD in that there is option for creating SDCard. You have give the specific size.it should be atleast 9MB and you have to add SDKimage file which in tools in androidSDK. When you have given you can create AVD with SDCard.